# unlink() is not working despite being given a valid file

Tags: php, unlink

I'm trying to delete some images from the server using PHP. However I keep running into this error:

Warning: unlink(/public_html/sandbox/resources/blocks/space004.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home//public_html/sandbox/application/blocks/models/m_blocks.php on line 503

Here is the unlink code:

```
if(unlink(SITE_ROOT . 'resources/blocks/' . $filename))
{
    $Template->setAlert($filename.' has been deleted successfully');
}
else 
{
    $Template->setAlert($filename.' has not been deleted', 'error');
}
```

I've checked in FTP that the file exists, it's in the exact path that's in the error (/public_html/sandbox/resources/blocks/). I've also checked file permissions, they're set to 0644 and changing to 0777 for testing purposes did nothing (as expected).

Anyone got an idea what might be causing this?

Comment: You have a `public_html` directory at the root of your server?

Comment: is SITE_ROOT properly defined?

Comment: You've got double `//` in `/home//public_html/..` Maybe start there

Comment: Ah ok, that was defined by somebody else before I inherited this code, I didn't even think about it =\

Answer (score 0):

`unlink` (and any other php function that works with files) works on the server and uses server paths.  `SITE_ROOT` seems to be the document root.  Instead, specify the full path to the file *on the server*

Comment: This makes sense, what is this likely to look like? Would it be (/home/public_html/........) like somebody suggested above? Or something different?

Comment: @Jonathon: I'm not sure why you'd think that we would know what your server's filesystem looks like...

Comment: I don't know, I thought there'd be a standard or something. I only have FTP access to the folder that has /public_html/ in it. If there's any folders higher than that then I can't see them and have no idea what they are...

Comment: Put a script somewhere that echoes the result of `getcwd()`.

Comment: do an `echo dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: @JonathonAshworth there is no standard at all about what any file system looks like (some particular OSen or distros may have their own standards, but you didn't say what yours is).  There is absolutely no consistent spot for where a server stores a website, and in fact the same server may run many domains at once